# Binding a Quarkus applications health check to HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: quarkus, smallrye

I am using the `quarkus-smallrye-health` extension in my Quarkus application. Our load balancer for our container platform requires that our application expose a health check endpoint over HTTP. For the other endpoints, I would like those to be exposed over HTTPS.

I've looked through the documentation but have not seen anything that would allow me to do this through Quarkus configuration parameters.

Comment: health check over http and the rest of endpoints over https? In the official doc runs the health check over http: https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-health#running-the-health-check

Comment: @Luisao That is because Quarkus runs over HTTP by default. Once Quarkus is configured to run over HTTPS, so does the health check.

Comment: I think it's just a workaround to redirect all HTTP request to HTTPS using ```quarkus.http.insecure-requests=redirect```
https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#disable-the-http-port